# How do I use GitHub with SSH without having to run ssh-agent?

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, ssh-agent

In order to push/pull from GitHub using SSH, I have to...

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/git_id_rsa
$ git push origin master
```

However, when I push/pull to remote git repositories I host on my own private server, I can skip the whole `ssh-agent` stuff and simply

```
$ git push origin master
```

How do I do the same with GitHub (push/pull without `ssh-agent` set-up and `ssh-add`)?

- My id_rsa keys **do not have passphrases** associated with them
- I am comfortable with the level of security this provides
- I know how to set-up bash aliases for these, and run them on start-up/bash exit, but I would rather not deal with them at all

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use config file in .ssh directory of your user in order to configure key for particular server:

```
# ~/.ssh/config
Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git_id_rsa
```

You can find more detail on [Simplify Your Life With an SSH Config File](http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/).

Comment: Worked! I was already using a `ssh_config` file, but my Host was `github.com:username`, and I had configs under that. I think one of those may have been the issue here.